# Como dar pause em videos do youtube, quando um novo vídeo é reproduzido?

Tags: iframe, vídeo, youtube, carousel, youtube-api

Tenho um website em que fiz um carousel de videos do YouTube usando o iframe, mas quando eu navego pelo carousel o vídeo continua tocando.

Como posso dar um pause automático quando um novo vídeo é reproduzido?

Comment: Veja se [isto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667882/how-to-pause-a-youtube-player-when-hiding-the-iframe) pode ajudar

Answer (score 1):

Para dar pause automático a um vídeo tens que usar a [API do YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) em vez do iframe padrão.

Esta API permite-te controlar coisas simples como eventos `play state`, `pause`, `stop` etc, ou ir até ao extremo e criar um reprodutor completamente personalizado à tua maneira.

Aqui está um exemplo de como seria o código para dar pause à transmissão de um reprodutor que se encontra atualmente a reproduzir, quando um novo vídeo é clicado:

**Exemplo no jsFiddle: [YouTube Pause/Play](https://jsfiddle.net/shuffledPixels/ayjgu6yw/)**

```
<div id="player1"></div>
<div id="player2"></div>
```

```
<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player1 = new YT.Player('player1', {
            height: '200',
            width: '520',
            videoId: 'glaG64Ao7sM',
            events: {
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
        player2 = new YT.Player('player2', {
            height: '200',
            width: '520',
            videoId: 'Z-48u_uWMHY',
            events: {
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
            pauseVideo(event.target.a.id);
        }
    }

    function pauseVideo(player_id) {
        if (player_id == "player1") {
            player2.pauseVideo();
        } else if (player_id == "player2") {
            player1.pauseVideo();
        }
    }
</script>
```

> Podes ler mais nesta documentação em Português:
>   [YouTube Player API - Primeiros Passos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started)